# How to perform single- and complete-linkage clustering based on selected pairwise compairsons?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

Let's say I have 8 objects.

```py
all_objects = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
```

I performed all pairwise comparisons (8 x 7) using a custom method. As a result, I got pairs that meet a certain similarity criterion.

```py
pairs = [
    ('A', 'B'),
    ('B', 'A'),
    ('B', 'D'),
    ('D', 'B'),
    ('D', 'C'),
    ('C', 'D'),
    ('E', 'F'),
    ('F', 'E'),
    ('F', 'G'),
    ('G', 'F'),
    ('E', 'G'),
    ('G', 'E'),
    ('H', 'G')
]
```

I want to transform the above pairs into clusters. Also, the edges connecting objects must be symmetric (e.g., `('A', 'B')` because there is also `('B', 'A')` but not `('H', 'G')`).

Specifically, I have two questions:

1. What is the code to perform single- and complete-linkage clustering based on the above pairs? Ideally, I would like to get clusters and name of objects in each cluster.
2. Are there any alternative methods of clustering this kind of data?

Answer (score 0):

You should include your first attempt at writing the code, so that people can help. We are unlikely to help if you have made no effort at all.

Here are some suggestions for steps:

#### 1. Filter the pairs, to keep only pairs where the reverse pair is also present.

Now there are no "dead ends" any more.

#### 2. Start a cluster with any pair, and add any objects that have a pair linking them to this cluster.

Now you have the biggest cluster you can obtain, from the pair that you chose.

Remove all pairs containing any object in your cluster, to make subsequent searches quicker.

#### 3. Pick any other pair, and repeat step 2, to form a new cluster.

Keep doing this until there are no more pairs remaining.